# Double foreach with if condition PHP

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, foreach, bootstrap-duallistbox

I need help because I have a problem of execution of my code.
In my database I store a multiple select like an array with this format : ["5","6","7","8"] I use json_encode to store my array.

I have a form with select multiple (https://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox).

This input is fill with datas of an table. So this is the list on the left who is filled.

I would like to fill the list on the right with my datas stored in database. To do this I have to put selected to each option corresponding.
But I have no idea to do this ... I think I use double foreach with an if condition but....

Some code to explain this:

Table with all options saved :
Table name : weddings
Fields : id, title

Table with selected options saved

Table name : steps
Fields : id, participants => this field has the number of weddings.id like ["5","6","7","8"]

To fill my select list, I do this

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="participants" class="form-control" name="participants[]">
    @foreach ($weddings as $wedding)
      <option value="{{ $wedding->id }}" >{{ $wedding->title }}  </option>
    @endforeach
</select>
```

To retrieve data from steps I do this

```
foreach(json_decode($step->participants) as $k => $v){
   echo '<option value="'.$v.'" selected>'.$v.'</option>';
}
```

Because I need to put 'selected' on an option, this one go to the right list.

How can I combine the 2 foreach to "selected" the value store in my steps table with weddings table ?

I hope you understand me.

Thank you very much.

PS : I use Laravel

Comment: is there two different select box as in the link or one single multi select box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, and most importantly understand it !

```
// select all participants
// for example lets say you got this from your database 
$data = '["5","7","9","2"]';
// now decode it 
$data = json_decode($data);

$weddings = [];
// convert values to integers 
foreach($data as $key => $value) 
{ 
   $weddings[$key] = (Int) $value; 
}

// create select input 
$input = '<select>';

foreach($weddings as $id) 
{
    // lets say you want wedding id 5 to be selected
    // all you have to do is add an If statement and that's it !
    if($id === 5) {
         // this is wedding id 5 ! 
         $input .= '<option value="'.$id.'" selected>'.$id.'</option>';
    } else if ($id === 7) {
          // do something with wedding id 7 ? 
         $input .= '<option value="'.$id.'" class="number7">'.$id.'</option>';
    } else {
         $input .= '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$id.'</option>';
    }
} 

// close select input tag 
$input .= '</select>';

echo $input;
```

Comment: You can also have the selected attribute in a php variable so you can output just once and it will be cleaner and easier to maintain.

Comment: yea but it won't be easier to understand i know i can do something like ( $weedingId === 5 ? 'selected' : '' ) which is much cleaner but not as easy to understand

Answer (score 0):

Amazing !!! It works.

But I need to change the close of the first foreach after the second because if not I have only the last item of the loop.

Thank you very much *azjezz*.

For info, this is my working code :

```
<div id="select-participants" class="form-group {{ $errors->has('participants') ? 'has-error' : '' }}">
        <label for="participants" class="col-sm-2 control-label">{!! $errors->has('participants') ? '<i class="fa fa-times-circle-o"></i>' : '' !!}Participants</label>
        <div class="col-sm-10">
                <select multiple="multiple" id="participants" class="form-control" name="participants[]">
                    @php
                        $export_json_participants = json_decode($preparationStep->participants);
                    @endphp
                        @foreach($export_json_participants as $key => $value)
                            $export_json_participants[$key] = $value;
                            @foreach ($weddings as $wedding)
                                <option value="{{ $wedding->id }}" {{ $wedding->id == $export_json_participants[$key] ? 'selected' : '' }}>{{ $wedding->title }}</option>
                            @endforeach
                        @endforeach
                 </select>
                @if ($errors->has('participants'))
                    <span class="help-block">
                        <strong>{{ $errors->first('participants') }}</strong>
                    </span>
                @endif
        </div>
    </div>
```

Thank you very much, and it's Ok, I understood. :-)